# centos 7+ nginx + php-fpm -> php-fpm not good work

Tags: php, nginx, centos7

### `Problem`

- php not page, but php file download.

### `State`

1. centos 7
2. nginx v1.10.0
3. php-fpm v5.4.16
4. nginx status - active(running)
5. php-fpm status - active(running)
6. http://[my_ip]/index.html -> working page
7. http://[my_ip]/index.php -> index.php file download. (i want working page)

### `Etc State`

1. i have file , /[my_nginx_root_dir]/index.php , /[my_nginx_root_dir]/index.html

Comment: Take a look at [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/).

Comment: it would be great if you can post the config file for your vhost

Comment: i solved - remove after, re config. (maybe config fail, i can not find bug config)